# How to use ng-repeat by table data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this array of 7 elements (7 arrays with 1 element each) I want to display 1 table row (because I have 1 element in each array) containing 7 table data. So the table output should be something like this:

```
   some label1 | some label2 | some label3 | some label4 | some label5 some label6 | some label7
0
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $scope.array = [
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      label: 'some label1'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      label: 'some label2'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 3,
      label: 'some label3'
    }
  ],
   [
    {
      id: 4,
      label: 'some label4'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 5,
      label: 'some label5'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 6,
      label: 'some label6'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 7,
      label: 'some label7'
    }
  ]
];
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in array"></tr> // this will generate 7 rows
</table>
```

Comment: like this `<td ng-repeat="column in array">{{column[0].label}}</td>` ?

Comment: @Maximus that will generate 7 rows

Comment: `tr` will generate rows, `td` will generate data columns

Comment: @PaulStoner I have edit my post

Comment: @que1326, `$scope.array` has 7 entries, how do you expect it to generate one row?  `<tr><td ng-repeat="column in array">{{column[0].label}}</td></tr>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="item in array">{{item[0].label}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is a working sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/sYo6YPuMmZ3B9EGhznkS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I would think if you parse the array items and concatenate them into a string then you should be able to do something like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-bind="scope variable name"/>
  </tr>
</table>
```